# How to Make USA States not required in Magento?

Tags: php, javascript, magento

When I change the country in the address book of magento, the states is not required when it is not USA.

how can I change it so it would mark as not required or won't be required anymore when I select USA?

Comment: Why would you not require a state when selecting the USA? I know this doesn't answer your question, but I'm simply curious as to the reason.

Comment: so i can figure out where to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

Go to System > Configuration > Genera > States Options

Set Display not required to NO.

Comment: This will also hide  State/Province at Checkout Page under "ESTIMATE SHIPPING AND TAX" block